# Netty: How can I acquire a single thread executor from an `EventLoop`?

Tags: java, performance, netty

How can I acquire a single thread executor from an `EventLoop`?

The reason being is I would like to use a single thread for one part of my application, but still have it be available for use by the `EventLoop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EventLoop is always just backed by a single thread. So the EventLoop in fact is just a single thread executor.

Comment: That seems to be true of the [existing implementations](http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/EventLoop.html), but is it required, either practically or by contract?

Comment: Well actually to be more precise this is for all EventLoop impls that extend SingleThreadEventExecutor. Which are all in Netty ;)